# Why does my jQuery queue stop working after executing once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, queue

Okay, so my goal is to make a simple animation where a domino moves from the front of a pile to the back, when it is clicked.

I have something that works here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kirkman/tDmHE/

But this consists of big series of nested callbacks, and eventually I will have a lot more than five dominoes. So then I learned that jQuery's queue could help me keep my code cleaner and not have to nest all those callbacks.

Here's what I came up with. But it only works the first time you click: http://jsfiddle.net/Kirkman/R7TmU/8/

What I cannot figure out is why it will not work subsequent times.

Here are the relevant JS functions:

```
    function dominoSlide(theThis) {
        $('#dominoes .nav ul li').removeClass('selected',500);
        var thisDomino = theThis.parent();
        $('#dominoes .nav ul').queue(function() {
            thisDomino.switchClass('domino0','selected', 250);
            $('.domino1').switchClass('domino1','domino0',10);
            $('.domino2').switchClass('domino2','domino1',10);
            $('.domino3').switchClass('domino3','domino2',10);
            $('.domino4').switchClass('domino4','domino3',10);
            thisDomino.addClass('domino4');
            thisDomino.removeClass('selected',250);
            resetHandlers();
        });
    }


    function resetHandlers() {
        $('#dominoes .nav ul li a').unbind();

        $('.domino0 a').bind('click', function(event) {
            var theThis = $(this);
            dominoSlide(theThis);
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#dominoes .nav ul li:not(".domino0") a').bind('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    }
```

Comment: Please include the actual code you need help with in the question itself.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using jQuery 1.3?

Comment: That's an oversight on my part. It should be 1.4.2, which is the version used on the site where this will eventually be implemented.

Comment: Someone earlier posted an answer suggesting that I use .live() instead of .bind(), but that answer was quickly deleted before I could respond. Just want to say that that answer was almost spot on. I now have my code working. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kirkman/aW4t7/

Comment: One other thing: The reason I used that resetHandlers() structure above was in an effort to allow only the first domino to be clicked. Using .live() instead of .bind(), and then wrapping the .click event handler with an `if ( !$('ul li').is(':animated') ) {` accomplished what I wanted much better. You can see this on the jsfiddle link directly above this comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dominoesHtml = $('.nav').clone().html();

            $('.story div').hide();

            $('.domino0 a').live('click', function (event) {
                var obj = $(this).parent();

                $('#dominoes .nav ul li').removeClass('selected', 500);
                obj.switchClass('domino0', 'selected', 250);
                $('.domino1').switchClass('domino1', 'domino0', 10);
                $('.domino2').switchClass('domino2', 'domino1', 10);
                $('.domino3').switchClass('domino3', 'domino2', 10);
                $('.domino4').switchClass('domino4', 'domino3', 10);
                obj.addClass('domino4');
                obj.removeClass('selected', 250);

                event.preventDefault();
            });

            $('button#btnReset').click(function () {
                $('.nav').html(dominoesHtml);
            });
        });    
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #dominoes
        {
            padding: 0px;
            width: 620px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        #dominoes .nav ul
        {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #dominoes .nav ul li
        {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 113px;
            top: 0px;
        }

        .domino0
        {
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
        .domino1
        {
            left: 30px;
            z-index: 98;
        }
        .domino2
        {
            left: 60px;
            z-index: 96;
        }
        .domino3
        {
            left: 90px;
            z-index: 94;
        }
        .domino4
        {
            left: 120px;
            z-index: 92;
        }

        .was0
        {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .was1
        {
            background-color: purple;
        }
        .was2
        {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .was3
        {
            background-color: green;
        }
        .was4
        {
            background-color: yellow;
        }


        #dominoes .nav ul li.hovered
        {
            padding-left: 50px;
        }


        #dominoes .nav ul li.selected
        {
            left: 506px;
            z-index: 1000;
        }

        .story
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 250px;
        }

        button
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dominoes">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="domino0 was0"><a href="xxx">
                    <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27409695/images/domino.png" />q</a></li>
                <li class="domino1 was1"><a href="xxx">
                    <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27409695/images/domino.png" />q</a></li>
                <li class="domino2 was2"><a href="xxx">
                    <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27409695/images/domino.png" />q</a></li>
                <li class="domino3 was3"><a href="xxx">
                    <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27409695/images/domino.png" />q</a></li>
                <li class="domino4 was4"><a href="xxx">
                    <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27409695/images/domino.png" />q</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button id="btnReset">
            Reset handlers
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```